# How can I fix my code to solve this case?

Tags: java

There is a Java coding question which returns `true` if the given non-negative number is 1 or 2 less than a multiple of 20. For example 38 and 39 it returns `true`, but 40 returns `false`.

**My code:**

```
public boolean less20(int n){
    if(n%20==0){
        return false;
    }else if(n>20 && n%20!=0){
        return false;
    }else if(20-n>2){
        return false;
    }else if((n+1)%20!=0||(n+2)%20!=0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

The code works on most cases, but some of them does not work at all, such as n=58 or n=59.

How can I fix my code and use the easiest way to solve this question?

Comment: for a simple solution, `(n + 1) % 20 == 0 || (n + 2) % 20 == 0` should do it.

Comment: I was confused about the mod method but now I totally understand it. thanks a lot:)

Comment: Step 1 to fix code: Format it (aka indent code) for human readability.

Comment: @1blustone Even simpler: `return n % 20 >= 18;`

Comment: You mentioned non-negative numbers so you should either throw an exception on negative or use `Math.floorMod` so that it works for negatives as well.